# Error when attempting to pass bundle, Android

Tags: android

I am attempting to pass selected items on a list to a new activity.

I declared an ArrayAdapter

ArrayAdapter madapter

Before OnCreate; in OnResume, I collect the data; and assign it to mAdapter

```
 //variable mAdapter
            //new ArrayAdapter string
            madapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    SearchingMidwife.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
                    locations);
            //set List to display mAdapter
```

And then I have this, that should allow for, when a listItem is clicked, to get selected items into a variable, and pass it to a new activity

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        //in checked, in listview get Item positions for checked items
        SparseBooleanArray checked = l.getCheckedItemPositions();

        //assign selected items to new String ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();


        //determine size of items checked (number)
        for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
            // Item position in adapter
            position = checked.keyAt(i);
            // Add location if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
            if (checked.valueAt(i))
                //add selected items to madapter
                selectedItems.add(madapter.getItem(position));
        }

        //create string output array, store new string array with selected items
        String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
            outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MidwifeResultList.class);

        // Create a bundle object
        Bundle b = new Bundle();


        b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);

        // Add the bundle to the intent.
        intent.putExtras(b);

        // start the ResultActivity
        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

I have a result activity that is designed to collect the selected item and display it:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_midwife_result_list);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        String[] resultArr = b.getStringArray("SelectedItems");

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultArr);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

When I run the program, I can see the listItem results, but when I select one the program stops, and there is this error:

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.bignerdranch.com.mobilemidwife/android.bignerdranch.com.mobilemidwife.MidwifeResultList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null

pointing to this line of code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultArr);
```

The code seems to be right...why would there be a null value on resultArr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);

...

String[] resultArr = b.getStringArray("SelectedItems");
```

You have a typo, in one place you write "selectedItems" and in another you write "SelectedItems". Notice the first letter is capitalized in one but not the other. You should change them to be the same.

Comment: @Michael Cabus, this is not the best practice to write static strings like this. If you do so, everywhere in your app will be full of meaningless magical strings. Use static variables for this.